# Tmux: disable preview window

Tags: tmux

When you press `prefix + s` or `prefix + w`, tmux displays preview window for windows.

How to disable this feature completely. I find it pretty annoying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may rebind the <kbd>s</kbd> and <kbd>w</kbd> keys.

The default key bindings are

- `choose-tree -Zs` for <kbd>s</kbd>
- `choose-tree -Zw` for <kbd>w</kbd>

Adding `-N` to these would make the preview not show up:

```
bind-key s choose-tree -ZsN
bind-key w choose-tree -ZwN
```

This would go in your `~/.tmux.conf` file, but you may activate it in the current session for testing with

```
tmux bind-key s choose-tree -ZsN
tmux bind-key w choose-tree -ZwN
```

on the shell's command line.

Would you want to see the preview at some point, just press <kbd>v</kbd> after executing the `choose-tree` command with <kbd>prefix</kbd>+<kbd>w/s</kbd>.